# Intercept leaving site, force destination into a new window

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I have a form that's embedded within an iframe in our website that I can't access. It's on a different server and there's nothing I can do to change it. It is a login form, and when submitted (using POST), goes to another website in the same window as my website. I want it to open in another tab/window.

So far I've determined that I can't manipulate the form inside the iframe with javascript, so as to add a new target to it, because of cross-browser security issues.

That leaves me with possibly trying to intercept the event of the page on my website closing, using the beforeunload event on a listener, like so:

```
window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function (e) {

  var confirmationMessage = "really?";
  (e || window.event).returnValue = confirmationMessage;     // Gecko and Trident
  return confirmationMessage;                                // Gecko and WebKit
});
```

This seems to at least intercept the action of leaving, but how do I then continue with leaving the page (data in post object intact), only in a new window this time?

Comment: The new URL is set at the time of firing this event (in your handler, `window.location.href` is already updated), but I don't think it's possible to also capture the POST data. If it is always a login form, wouldn't it be possible to replace some of its contents with server-side means?

Comment: Thank you for the answer @JánosWeisz ! The solution was staring me in the face. We will simply open the page containing the iframe in a new tab/window. Duh. :)